# CASE or IF Statement in Linq Query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

is there a way of including a CASE or if conditional statement inside a LINQ query? I'm trying to build my select statement dynamically depending on the parameter passed into the method.

Here's how I'd write it in T SQL:

```
select * from Table1 
where Table1Id = 
      CASE WHEN LEN myParameter > 0
      THEN myParamter
      ELSE Table1.Table1Id
```

Here's my Linq Query with the SQL CASE shoved in:

```
  var query = from a in Table1
               where a.Table1Id== 
                    CASE WHEN LEN myParameter > 0
                    THEN myParamter
                    ELSE Table1.Table1Id
                            && a.shortName == myParameter2
                            && a.Country == myParameter3
                            select a;

                return query.ToList();
```

This sort of thing...

Looks like I can use the `myParameter.Length()` method but not sure where to start with the syntax?

Ok, here goes, the entire original SQL Statement method:

```
 string nativeSQLQuery = string.Format("SELECT c.ArticleId ,
                                                + "c.ArticleTitle,"
                                                + c.Version,
                                                + "c.shortName,c.Country,c.ArticleHeader,c.ArticleBody,"
                                                + "c.DateCreated,c.UserCreated,c.DateUpdated,c.UserUpdated,"
                                                + "c.isPublished"
                                                + "c.isBreakingNews"
                                            + " FROM ISES.vwArticles c "
                                            + " WHERE c.ArticleTitle = "
                                            + "     CASE WHEN LEN('{1}') > 0"
                                            + "     THEN '{1}'"
                                            + "     ELSE c.ArticleTitle"
                                            + "     END "
                                            + " AND c.shortName = "
                                            + "     CASE WHEN LEN('{2}') > 0"
                                            + "     THEN '{2}'"
                                            + "     ELSE c.shortName"
                                            + "     END "
                                            + " AND c.Country = "
                                            + "     CASE WHEN LEN('{3}') > 0"
                                            + "     THEN '{3}'"
                                            + "     ELSE c.Country"
                                            + "     END "
                                            + " AND c.articleid NOT IN "
                                            + " (SELECT pa.articleid FROM ISES.tbPublicationArticles pa "
                                            + " WHERE pa.publicationid={0})", publicationId, ModelSelectedArticleTitle, vRegionShortName, ModelSelectedCountryshortName);
```

Comment: Are you trying to migrate a stored procedure with "optional" parameters to LINQ? You don't have to do that as @James shows. You can append `Where()` clauses to your `Queryable<>` and LINQ to Entities will create the appropriate SQL statement

Answer (score 4):

The conditional filtering doesn't have to be part of the query itself, LINQ statements use deferred loading therefore you can build a dynamic query

```
var query = someList;
if (myParameter > 0) {
    // dynamic filter
    query = query.Where(x => x.Table1Id == myParameter);
}
```

Alteratively written as a one-liner

```
var query = myParameter > 0 ? someList : someList.Where(x => x.Table1Id == myParameter);
```

---

Your existing code re-written

```
var query = _Context.vwArticles
    .Where(x => a.ArticleTitle == modelSelectedArticleTitle &&
                a.shortName == regionShortName &&
                a.Country == modelSelectedCountryshortName);
if (myParameter > 0) {
    query = query.Where(x => x.Table1Id == myParameter);
}
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: That's only possible if the condition is constant throughout the query, and know before executing the query.  If it's dependent on data in the row, for example, then this is not possible.

Comment: @Servy in the example above, that would *appear* to be the case.

Comment: @Servy I don't think you can express a `SELECT CASE` with LINQ. This is definitely *another* case where ORMs shouldn't be used as SQL replacements. A view with the required query would be a lot more readable and maintainable

Comment: Question edited to include my LINQ so far. The developer working on this before me has written this in native SQL, I can see why he's done it that way but I'd rather stick to LINQ if possible as his solution is messy & a lot of code]

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the OP is after a `WHERE` filter, not a `SELECT` one.

Comment: Oops, just noticed and it *shouldn't* be there. That's *bad* SQL, used to create so called "optional parameters", which result in inappropriate execution plans. Since a param's value *is* constant, the OP should just append the proper `.Where()` statement

Answer (score -1):

Use the conditional operator:

```
var query = from item in table
    let table1Id = myParameter.Length() > 0 ? myParameter : item.Table1Id
    select item;
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Given that it's got a 1:1 mapping from the conditional operator to the `CASE` statement, I'd certainly expect it to work.  It's of course possible that EF didn't bother to support it.

Comment: All `let` does here is determine what `table1Id` will be set as, the `where` filter is still missing.

Comment: @Chris It computes the necessary value, which can then be used however the OP wants, whether that be in a `where`, a `select`, or whatever else.  He has the needed value, which is the part that he doesn't know how to do.

Comment: Just noticed, the `CASE` is in the `WHERE` clause. It's an attempt to move into SQL a (bad) technique for passing "optional" parameters in stored procedures.

Comment: @James I'm quite confident in the OP's ability to add a `where` that uses the value to filter the items however he wants.  It solves the problem that he didn't know how to solve.  And of course it's a toy example anyway; it's not like that was his real code.

Comment: I suspect the original sproc contains code like `AND (@param IS NULL OR SomeField=@Param)

Comment: @Servy it's not the point, the solution is misleading as it suggests that this is all the OP needs to achieve what they want, perhaps mentioning that the `WHERE` filter is omitted would help...

Comment: @Chris You honestly feel that the OP is incapable of adding a `where` clause that uses an assigned variable?  Seriously?

Comment: @James It's not the OP's *actual* code in the first place.  It's a toy example designed to demonstrate the use of a `CASE` statement and is asking how to set it up.  The rest of the query isn't his actual query anyway; it's entirely tangential to the actual question being asked, which is how to write a `CASE` statement.

Comment: @Chris He *didn't* ask that though.  He asked how to write a `CASE` statement in LINQ, as is done in the following example.  The question is asking how to represent a `CASE`, not how to map some query that happens to contain a `CASE`.  You seem to be focusing on how to create answers with nothing but code to be copy-pasted without understanding, rather than providing answers that answer the question in a way that results in the reader actually understanding the solution, and being able to apply it to *any* situation.

Comment: I agree with Chris, the crux of the question is about conditional filtering but your answer only demonstrates how you can use `let` with no, even fictitious, example of how that variable is then used to filter records. It's A. incomplete & B. confusing to readers.

Comment: @James So you assume anyone reading this post has no idea what a `where` clause is or how to write one?  Are you serious?  The crux of the question is how to represent a `CASE`.  Now about how to write a `where` clause in SQL.  This answer shows how to do that and then allows that value to be used in *any* context, whether that be a `where`, `select`, or literally anything else.  For someone to be unable to use it in a `where` they would need to literally be incapable of just writing a basic `where`, and such a person shouldn't be looking at this question in the first place.

Comment: @Servy all I'm saying is it's potentially misleading as you are clearly directly answering the question but then providing an example which consequently doesn't satisfy the expected result. For example, if someone read this question and then followed your code example it wouldn't give them the desired results, all you would need is a little context to your answer to indicate that but you appear to stubborn to do that, even though it appears to have already confused one reader (Chris).

Comment: @James It's a toy example.  It's not designed to be run at all; it's not his real situation, everything other than the `CASE` is just code stuffed around the `CASE` to make it a complete example.  The actual conditional operation is what's relevant.

Comment: @Servy if the code snippet was never intended to be useful then why bother even writing it, I'd argue that this answer is as good as a link to documentation.

Comment: @Chris I didn't say that my opinion was right.  I've merely expressed my views as you expressed yours.  You claimed that you thought someone else might be unable to use my answer to solve their problem due to it not explaining something you felt was relevant.  You're *guessing* that someone else *might* not know how to use this answer to answer their question, given that it doesn't exactly match the code in the question.  This of course despite the fact that such a reader is of course going to have their own code, not the exact code in the question.

Comment: @James It's an *example*.  Meant to demonstrate example usage of an operator.  It's not meant to be a copy-paste solution for the problem described in the question, given that it was clear that that was never the goal of the question.  It uses the operator in an intentionally *generalized* manor, rather than adding some specific context.  Storing the computed value in a `let` lets it be used anywhere in the query, for anything, rather than *just* a `where` or *just* a `select`.